# What does $g(f(x))=x$ imply?

Tags: proof-writing, inverse

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ be functions such that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$.

**(a)** Prove that $f$ is injective.

**(b)** Prove that $g$ is surjective.

**(c)** Give an example of a pair of functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ and neither $f$ nor $g$ is bijective.

I know that $g(f(x))=x$ implies $g=f^{-1}$.
If we know that $f$ has an inverse, does that automatically imply the function is injective and surjective? How?

Comment: $g=f^{-1}$ means $gf=1$ **and** $fg=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has an inverse, than this automatically implies that $f$ is injective and surjective: $f$ is injective because $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$, applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides. $f$ is surjective, because given any $y\in Y$ we have $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$. That is $f(X)=Y$.

**But**: Notice how we needed both equations, $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ *and* $f^{-1}(f(x))$ in that deduction? If you have just $f(g(x))=x$ or $g(f(x))=x$, then this implies only that $f$ is surjective or injective, respectively. For bijectivity you need both equations!

Regarding your problems:

**(a)**: Assume $f(x)=f(y)$. How can you show $x=y$?

**(b)**: Let $x\in X$. How can you find $y\in Y$ such that $g(y)=x$?

**(c)**: Let $X=\{0\}$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $f=g=0$. Then

$$g(f(0))=0$$

but clearly $f,g$ are not bijective.

Comment: For **(c)**, I'm partial to the example $X = Y = c_c$ (q.v. [sequence space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space)) and the maps $S_R(x_1,x_2,\dotsc) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dotsc)$ and $S_L(x_1,x_2,\dotsc) = (x_2,\dotsc)$. Then $S_L \circ S_R$ is the identity, but neither is bijective nicely illustrating the difference between linear algebra in infinite dimensions and finite dimensions (which more or less boils down to a vector space being free on any of its bases and maps on finite sets being bijective iff they're in- or surjective).

Comment: Yes, nice example. @kahen